# Sammy link hit twice only runs once

Tags: routes, sammy.js

I would like to make a Sammy route run twice if I click the following link "...111" twice in a row.

I am using FireFox 35.0.1 and Fire Bug.

I start FireFox

I click Fire bug

I click console in the Fire bug section at the bottom of Fire Fox.

I run my code from my local machine.

I click the link ...111

The fire bug console show the log message "another page with id = 111"

I click the link ...111 again

The fire bug console doesn't show a new log message

I click the link ...343

The fire bug console show the log message "another page with id = 343"

I click the link ...111

The fire bug console show the log message "another page with id = 111"

...

If I switch between the two links the message is always displayed.

If I hit the same link two or more times the message is only shown once.

How do I make the links always run even if they are clicked two or more times
in a row?

I need to do this because when a user hits F5 or clicks refresh
on our production system the page isn't being reloaded and is displaying old
information.

I think this is being caused by Sammy and I don't know Sammy and
have to fix the problem.

Below is the code:

```js
​
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <!-- 
    Code modified from:
    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16040732/sammy-routing-not-working
    http://jsbin.com/oyujib/1/#/

    -->

    <html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sammy.js/0.6.3/sammy.min.js"></script>
        <title>twoLinksNoRefresh.htm</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a href="#/another/343/">click 343</a><br />
        <a href="#/another/111/">click 111</a><br />
        If I click the same link twice in a row, the log is only written once to the console in FireFox 35.0.1 with Fire Bug.<br />
        Is there a way to make the log statement run each time I click the same link more then one time in a row?<br />
        If I alternate clicking on the 343 link and then the 111 link it works fine.<br />
        Thanks<br />
        <script type="text/javascript">
            (
                function ($)
                {

                    $.sammy(
                        function ()
                        {

                            this.get('#/', function (context) {
                                context.log("start page");
                            });

                            this.get("#/another/:id/", function (context) {
                                context.log("another page with id = " + context.params["id"]);
                            });
                        }
                    ).run('#/');
                }
            )(jQuery);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Thanks